# new <T> in Java

Tags: java, generics, instantiation

I have this problem

a method which is cutting unwanted details from one class and returning collection of objects with wanted ones. the matter is I want this metod to be able to work with different classes ( which are based on one abstract, though), so I use generic type. the problem is that in one point I need to create an instance of , which is impossible. I looked for some way out, but it doesn't seem to work for my case. 
So, code is following

```
 private <T extends RestMandate> List<T> toRestMandate(List<CardMandate> mandates ) {
    List<T> restMandates = new ArrayList<>(mandates == null ? 0
            : mandates.size());
    if (mandates != null) {
        for (CardMandate mandate : mandates) {
             restMandates.add(new T(mandate));
        }
    }

    return restMandates;
}
```

RestMandate is base class, CardMandate were I take the info. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to simply convert from `List<CardMandate>` to `List<RestMandate>`?

Comment: practically yes) the matter is that object of CardMandate has too many arguments and I am *taking* them out. In case you have other, simpler solution for this I would be grateful)

Comment: What do you mean *object has too many arguments?*

Comment: pardon, has too many fields( taken from DB, and I don't need them)

Comment: Well, now is the time to show some example. It is not making complete sense. You can't remove attributes from an object. Are you stuck with handling superclass-subclass relationship. Whatever it is, post an example.

Comment: Card mandate has Id, Name, Number, Address and for my RestMandate I need only Id and Number. other classes, based on RestMandate would use other fields (Id, Name or Id, Address) depending on what they need to return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the generic type arguments are erased at runtime, there is no way you can refer to it like you are trying to do. The only way out is a type tag argument + reflective instantiation.

A better choice is to redesign your solution to solve this without relying on generics and type tags. Leverage dynamic method dispatch instead: add a method to `RestMandate` which will return the object converted to the desired type.

Comment: I understand, but I like this method) it is so nice, except this thing with instantiating. I would do it in Factory pattern in case no solution would help

Comment: It *would* be nice in some other language which has reified type paremeters :)

Answer (score 3):

Because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6), T becomes Object at runtime. You don't know its real type anymore.

You can still instantiate the object by reflection if you have its class. In order to do that, you must give the class to your method:

```
private <T extends RestMandate> List<T> toRestMandate(List<CardMandate> mandates, Class<T> clazz ) {
  ...
  for (CardMandate mandate : mandates) {
     /*
      * I get the constructor which needs one CardMandate and call it.
      * Note : I do not recommend this solution (no check at compile-time!). 
      * Like Marko Topolnik, I advise to redesign the solution.
      */
     restMandates.add(clazz.getConstructor(CardMandate.class).newInstance(mandate));
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: He is using parameterized constructor. `newInstance()` needs a 0-arg constructor.

Comment: I cannot call this one. it keeps saying that types do not match.

List<CardMandate> cardMandates;
List<ExpiringCard> restMandate;
toRestMandate(cardmandates, restMandate);

Comment: The second argument must be a class, not a List.  Pass `ExpiringCard.class` as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

To create an instance you require `Class<T>` object too

```
private <T extends RestMandate> List<T> toRestMandate(List<CardMandate> mandates, Class<T> clazz) {
    //....
    T newInst = clazz.newInstance();

    //....
}
```

Comment: I've seen this one, newInstance has troubles with exceptions, and program doesn't want to support variant with Constructor.newInstance()

Comment: He is using parameterized constructor. `newInstance()` needs a 0-arg constructor.